# Steps of proof using set theory?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have been asked to prove the following proposition:

> $A \cup (A \cap B) = A$

I have been able to apply the law of distributivity to get so far but need some advice on how to completely prove the proposition.

Comment: What did you get with the dist. law??

Comment: (A∪A)∩(A∪B) = A

Comment: @Gh But $\;A\cup A=A\;$ trivially, so that didn't actually help at all, did it?

Comment: Siong Thye Goh's hint should be sufficient, but just as a reminder- proving $A=B$ is equivalent to proving $A\subseteq B$ and $B\subseteq A$.

Comment: @Ghoohio As a rule of thumb, you should always include your try at the problem in question. Otherwise you will get downvotes and close votes.

Answer (score 2):

We prove two directions:

"$A \cup (A \cap B) \subseteq A$": Let $x \in A \cup (A \cap B)$. We want to show that $x \in A$. Since $x \in A \cup (A \cap B)$ we have $x \in A$ **or** $x \in A \cap B$. If $x \in A$ we are done. So suppose $x \in A \cap B$, then we have $x \in A$ **and** $x \in B$, so we are done as well.

"$A \cup (A \cap B) \supseteq A$": Let $x \in A$. We want to show that $x \in A \cup (A \cap B)$. Being $x \in A \cup (A \cap B)$ means that $x \in A$ **or** $x \in A \cap B$. Since $x \in A$, we get $x \in A \cup (A \cap B)$.

I hope it helps you :)

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$A \cap B \subset A$$

If $C \subset A$, what do you know about $C \cup A$?

Hint $2$:

Another hint to proceed on from where you have reached:

You want to show that $$A \cap (A \cup B)=A$$

Notice that $$A \subset A \cup B$$

If $A \subset C$, what do you know about $C \cap A$?

Answer (score 1):

let $x \in A\cap B$

$\implies x \in A$

$\implies A\cap B \subseteq A$

$\implies A \cup (A \cap B) \subseteq A \qquad \qquad(1)$

let $x \in A$

$\implies x \in A \cup (A \cap B)$

$\implies A \cup (A \cap B) \supseteq A \qquad \qquad(2)$

From $(1)$ and $(2)$

$\implies A = A\cup(A\cap B)$